# how to Test React Hook State Changes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

This my class `Query`:

```js
export default class Query {
    constructor(env, query, updateQuery) {
        this.query = query //
        this.env = env
        this.updateQuery = updateQuery
    }
    
    generateDefault() {
        const routers = this.env.routers
    
        return {
            ipVersion: constants.SelectorIPVersion.choices[0].id,
            network: constants.SelectorNetwork.choices[0].id,
            router: routers && routers.length > 0 ? routers[0].id : null,
            command: constants.SelectorCommands.choices[0].id,
                parameters: {
                id: 'myIP',
                value: this.env.myIP.ipv4,
                isValid: true,
            },
        }
    }
    
    reset() {
        this.updateQuery(this.generateDefault())
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

```js
export default function LookingGlassPanelContainer(props) {
    const { env, isServerDown } = props
    const defaultQuery = new Query(env).generateDefault()
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(defaultQuery)
    let _query = new Query(env, query, setQuery)
    //rest of code
}
```

```
› handleReset

TypeError: this.updateQuery is not a function

  131 |
  132 |   reset() {
> 133 |     this.updateQuery(this.generateDefault())
      |          ^
  134 |   }
  136 |   setRequestTimeout() {

  at Query.reset (src/LookingGlass/components/Query/Query.js:133:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/LookingGlass/components/Query/Query.test.js:86:24)
```

My test case:

```js
describe( 
    //here i have defined const query and const env
    it('handleReset', () => { 
        let _query = new Query(env, query) 
        console.log(_query.reset()) 
    }) 
)
```

After writing test case for `Query` found error, can anyone please help me what does this error mean?
I am new to react so I don't know how to maintain state in test case.
I don't know how to pass `setQuery` in test case as `setQuery` is setter.
I don't want to change my code, I can change my test case but not code.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do state changes. As @Oli already mentioned, you're not calling the `Query` class properly in your test. You need to pass an `updateQuery` as third argument to your `new Query(env, query)` call for it not to error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a `updateQuery` param to your constructor.

Your class is expecting 3 arguments:

```js
  constructor(env, query, updateQuery) {
    this.query = query //
    this.env = env
    this.updateQuery = updateQuery
  }
```

Your `reset` function is depending on `updateQuery` being a function:

```js
  reset() {
    this.updateQuery(this.generateDefault())
  }
```

And in your `<LookingGlassPanelContainer />` component, you are only passing in `env`:

```js
const defaultQuery = new Query(env).generateDefault()
```

Which means `updateQuery` is not defined, and the class is expecting it to be a function.

Whatever `updateQuery` should be, you need to pass it to the constructor, when you are initialising it:

```js
const defaultQuery = new Query(env, null, () => {}).generateDefault()
```

...

**EDIT**

You updated the question with your test case:

To quote your test:

```
it('handleReset', () => { let _query = new Query(env, query) 
   console.log(_query.reset()) }) )
```

It is the same problem here as well. You have not passed the `updateQuery` function to the class.

Comment: my test case:                                                                                                                           
  -describe(  here i have defined const query and const  env                                                it('handleReset', () => {
    let _query = new Query(env, query)
    console.log(_query.reset())
  }) )

Comment: Not in the test, inside of `<LookingGlassPanelContainer />`. When you are calling `new Query(...)`, you are not passing an `updateQuery` function as an argument. This isn't a React problem, it is just you're not initialising the class properly inside of the React Component.

Comment: thanks for answer,but  i am using  let _query = new Query(env, query, setQuery) for accessing methods of Query class.                                                                                                                                  I want to pass setQuery in test case i.e setter but i dont know how to maintain state in test case??

Comment: Please check the answer again - it is this line `const defaultQuery = new Query(env).generateDefault()` that is the problem.

Comment: I tried const defaultQuery = new Query(env, null, () => {}).generateDefault() but still i have error in test case . because i have not used state in test case and haven't pass in test case.

Comment: I've extended the answer because you added your test case. It's the same problem, remember `new Query` is expecting 3 arguments.

Comment: i haven't add setQuery because i don't know to pass it in test case . setQuery is useState i used in class file .